# Azure audit logging for API Calls wihtin a service principal

Tags: azure, audit, service-principal

is there any way to log the ip address of an API call for an Application (Service Principal), which is not in the global catalogue? Also, i don´t see any information within Graph API.

What i´ve also tried:

- Logs directly within the Enterprise Application
- Cloud App Security
- Azure Sentinal.

Thanks!